# Calling Google Protocol RPC API in Browser via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, google-app-engine-python, protorpc

I'm trying to access a [Google Protocol RPC API](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/protorpc/) with jQuery like this:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url: some_url,
    type: "POST",
    data       : some_params,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType   : "json",
    success    : function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        },
    error      : function (xhr, status, errorThrown) {
        console.log(xhr);
    }
});
```

But I only get the following error message:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://*****. Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 400
```

How can I return an `OPTIONS`method in ProtoRPC, that I don't get this error anymore?

Comment: This error sometimes occurs because the receiver was expecting a GET instead of a POST

Comment: I should mention, that the API works perfectly when called via CURL or Postman or similar tools.

Comment: I know little curl, but ... please, could you paste a example with curl?.... It may be a good clue

Comment: curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json"  -d some_params
' "the url"

Comment: I really don't think, that the post request itself is the problem. My guess is, that, as Google Chrome is doing a preflight request via OPTIONS, this is the problem